# Javascript Phaser cross-origin error

Tags: javascript, image, phaser-framework

I made a game using html, javascript, and the Phaser library. It works perfectly fine on my localhost. However when I upload it to Github (via the web interface), and run it, it gives this error:

> Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'texImage2D' on 'WebGLRenderingContext': The cross-origin image at http://www.imagesup.net/dt-1514207740759.png may not be loaded.

Could someone please explain what I'm doing wrong, and how to fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Download the pics you need, put it in a resource folder on your own server, then load that using the local file path.

Answer (score 1):

Because has a different domain and security restrictions must enable CORS in the Server to make HTTP requests.

Answer (score 0):

The images must be in your uploaded folders, you can't be loading them via an online URL. If you're making a Phaser game, might I recommend [phaser-plus generator](https://github.com/rblopes/generator-phaser-plus). It is an awesome way to bootstrap your project with basic configuration figured out for you.